# react-native-media-meta Working while debug but crashing on Release APK

Tags: android, react-native

To read selected media metadata for our `react-native` application, we've used `react-native-media-meta`. It causing issue in released APK but working fine in debug.

Package link : https://github.com/mybigday/react-native-media-meta
I got success in reading media meta data, application is working fine for both `iOS` and `Android` in debug. 
While in release APK, app throws an `Exception` as below :

`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "J" field "mNativeContext" in class "Lwseemann/media/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever;" or its superclasses at wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.native_init(Native Method) at wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.<clinit>(Unknown Source:43) at com.mybigday.rnmediameta.RNMediaMeta.getMetadata(Unknown Source:19) at com.mybigday.rnmediameta.RNMediaMeta.access$000(Unknown Source:0) at com.mybigday.rnmediameta.RNMediaMeta$1.run(Unknown Source:8)`

In release only `Exception` is there. I follow that specific library description that used for `Android` in `react-native-media-meta` from here : https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever#using-fmmr-in-your-application-android-studio

But still, if I'll do release architecture based APK same result it gives. If I declare multiple dependancies for each architecture it generate `dependancy duplication` issue.

Currently this single issue is a hurdle in building released Android APK. Any help would be appreciated, for how can I overcome this issue.

similar issues:
1. https://github.com/mybigday/react-native-media-meta/issues/22 
2. https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever/issues/197

Comment: Did the release worked a single time since you installed this plugin ? If it did, it might be a version problem

Comment: Not a single time the release worked. In release, `react-native-media-meta` failed to locate `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever` class.

Comment: react-native-media-meta doesn't work on release apk, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @PurvikRana Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this by adding these lines in progaurd-rules.pro file

- -keep class com.mybigday.** { *; }
- -keep class com.mybigday.rnmediameta.** { *; }
- -keep class wseemann.media.** {*;}

it solved the issue in the Release build.